# How do I make the eval function safe?

Tags: javascript

I am working on an interactive Canvas tutorial. I want the students to be able to enter JavaScript into a contenteditable element, but I am afraid that it could introduce vulnerabilities.

I have thought about re-assigning dangerous objects or methods before evaluating their code, and then assigning it back afterwards.

How do I determine the dangerous objects?

Is this the right approach, or should I rather scan their input and only allow certain statements?

Comment: A good read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil

Comment: While the question is interesting it has been asked a lot of times as well as when googling for the exact title several articles and SO posts are displayed and 3rd party APIs able to use eval safely.

Comment: do you run those javascript codes from one student on other ones pcs? or every student work with his own copy?

Comment: What exactly do you think is vulnerable? What's your threat model, what things do you need to protect?

Comment: About *everything* is dangerous in JS. You can't get away with a blacklist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to give general advice without knowing details but you might want to investigate putting your editable content in a sandboxed iframe.

```
<iframe sandbox="allow-scripts"></iframe>
```

You would need to test for support which the https://modernizr.com library supports. Also setting appropriate [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy) headers may be needed depending on how you implement this.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. I didn't know about this feature. I will test it out. If I understand correctly, the thing that makes this safe is that it gets a unique origin, so basically it is treated as if it was a script from another source.

Comment: @PalleCogburn that's right. It's as though the contents of the iframe is on a domain all of its own.

Answer (score 0):

How about providing a bunch of [JSBin](http://www.jsbin.com/) playpens that the students can then fork and edit?

This takes the security question out of your hands.

Answer (score -1):

What about running their JS code inside a JS 'VM' like https://www.npmjs.com/package/vm2 ? It's basically a JS runtime like eval in which you can declare what's available. You can for example prevent access to the fs lib.